# how to write into excel with the header follow exactly the dictionary keys?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I do have a list of 20000++ dictionaries with 59 keys and values. I need to export the dictionary into excel. Below is my script using pandas to write into excel but the problem is the header did not follow the correct position of the key in dictionary. Below is just some part of the list.

```
new_d=[{'file': '1_2', 'name': 'paul', 'role': 'engineer',.....},
       {'file': '1_2', 'name': 'smith', 'role': 'engineer',....},
       {'file': '1_2', 'name': 'mei', 'role': 'engineer',.....}
        . 
        .
        . ]
```

Here is my code to export the list into an excel using pandas

```
ccf_df=pd.DataFrame(a)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
ccf_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='FCC')
```

Unfortunately, the output in the excel file is not following the correct position of the key in the dictionary.

It was supposedly to be `file|name|role|actor|time|.....` but the output is `actor|file|time|role|name|.....`

Comment: This is possibly because python's dictionary does not preserve key order. Maybe try OrderedDict (which does preserve key order) and see if that makes a difference? See docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: But you can specify the order of the columns during `df.to_excel("data.xlsx", columns=[A,B,C])`

Answer (score 1):

You can force pandas excel writer to keep the order of the columns the way you want by giving `columns=[list of columns]`
`ccf_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='CCF', columns=[list of columns])`